# Nodes of eigenfunctions and Courant's nodal domain theorem

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a reference for properties of eigenfunctions of the Laplacian (on the Euclidean plane, and maybe also Laplace-Beltrami on a general manifold):

- The discreteness of the set of eigenvalues,
- Nodes of eigenfunctions,
- Courant's nodal domain theorem,
- The Faber-Krahn inequality,

and other related results.

I have tried *Methods of Mathematical Physics (Courant, Hilbert)* but it contains only some of the above, is quite old and a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently read the following survey of various results about the spectrum of the Laplacian (on Euclidean domains, though many results carry over directly to the Laplace-Beltrami operator). You might find it, and its references, helpful: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1278.pdf

Comment: This is an amazing survey. I am working in my master's thesis on nodal sets of eigenfunctions and this is going to help a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Adding a second answer to my own question for everyone's benefit:

In the past month I have been reading *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry* by *Isaac Chavel*, and it is a good book for these subjects.